# Why use shadier if can use mesh property?

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, glsl, shader

I am working with shaders in THREE.js and the example I am following shows how to create waving flag effect with a plane mesh. The result is a plane with z coordinates waving as so in picture.
I only have a basic understanding of shaders but my question is why use shader to change 'modelPosition.z' when we can just do same using mesh.position.z in main javascript file where THREE.Mesh is instanciated? Are shaders just a way of creating custom materials?

```
        uniform vec2 uFrequency;
        uniform float uTime;

        
        attribute float aRandom;
        

        
        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying float vElevation;

        void main()
        {
            //gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
            //gl_Position.x += 0.5;
            //gl_Position.y += 0.5;


            vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

            float elevation = sin(modelPosition.x * uFrequency.x - uTime) * 0.1;
            elevation += sin(modelPosition.y * uFrequency.y - uTime) * 0.1;
            modelPosition.z += elevation;

            vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;
            vec4 projectedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;
            gl_Position = projectedPosition;

           
            vUv = uv;
            vElevation = elevation;
        }
```

[image: flag]

Comment: Shaders run on the GPU. The code runs in parallel for all vertices.

Comment: `mesh.position.z` will shift your mesh awhole, whereas you need to shift geometry's vertices individually. So you have to work with a buffer attributes `mesh.geometry.attributes.position`, and change z-value of each vertex in accordance with a function.